# Node https get file from url and unzip

Tags: node.js, http, request, unzip

I am using node https/http module to download file. The code looks like this:

```
https.get(url)
.on('response', (response) => {
    response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dataDir + filename))
}
```

In the next step I use [unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip) module to unzip the file.

```
fs.createReadStream(dataDir + filename)
.pipe(unzip.Extract({path: dataDir}))
.on('close', () => { something }
.on('error', () => { catch error}
```

For most cases, Everything works well. However, sometimes unzip module returns this error:

```
Error: invalid signature: 0x6d74683c
```

The only issue I can notice is the file name. I grab filename from url. It is the last parameter of a url.  However, in some cases, the exact filename is different from the one shown in url. For instance:

```
https://github.com/request/request/archive/master.zip
```

The name shown in url is `master.zip` but when I download it the name is  `request-master.zip`.

Is this the actual problem? If so, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The filename is most likely a symptom rather than the root cause. The `unzip` module is unmaintained and has many open issues. It is likely to blame and should not be used, regardless.

Try out [decompress](https://github.com/kevva/decompress) or [yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) instead. Also, since you are attempting to extract the archive in a stream, you may want to read about how that is [not truly possible](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#no-streaming-unzip-api).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try yauzl at first.